# Problem with upgrade to 20.04 affect Windows as well

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I have an asus rog strix with ubuntu (installed as main OS) and Windows 10.
In ubuntu I have a steam installation with some games.
Yesterday I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. During the upgrade, appear the error:

```
Installed nvidia-dkms-435 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
```

Now the games on steam are unplayable, it shows maybe 2 fps.
The problem is that the windows is broken as well! The mouse animation is so slow that I cannot use it.
How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

I update the Nvidia driver on Ubuntu from 435 to 440, and I set the microsoft boot loader as default (instead of GNU Grub).
Now all works perfectly